# VB6: Trying to use multiple variables while saving txt using Line input

Tags: vb6

I just recently began programming in VB6 as apart of my highschool curriculum. My main problem has to do with Line Input when trying to save to text files.

Say I have the variables x,y and I print them onto a text file like so:

```
Print #1, x, y
```

If I try to access them through using line input like:

```
Line Input #1, SavedX, SavedY
```

I get an Error.

But If i print them like this:

```
Print #1, x
 Print #1, y
```

and then try to access them like this:

```
Line Input #1, SavedX
   x = SavedX
Line Input #1, Savedy
   y = SavedY
```

I don't come across any error.

Is it possible to hold both x and y values in the same line using Line Input? or am i forced to use the method i just mentioned?

Sorry if my explanation sucked but it was the best way I thought I explained it.

Comment: VB.NET IsNot VB6 AndAlso IsNot vba - I removed the tag

Comment: I am wondering why a school chooses to teach a language as VB6 today.

Comment: @Steve I wonder too, but every time in the past I have asked if that was *really* the case, it was (with bizarre answers like 'VB.NET takes too long to configure' which I take to mean *teacher dont know NET*).

Comment: it's werid cause i consider my school well funded and when I heard we were learning a obsolete language such as VB6 I almost fell over in my chair.  Sadly this is a prerequisite for university so i must take it.

Comment: VB6 is probably older than you are - the really sad thing is that any day now a new Windows version could come out which wont run it - its under the "It Just Works" category (== too bad if/when it doesnt).  Not a lot of call for VB6 programmers these days either

Comment: As you can read on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243392(v=vs.60).aspx) Line Input read a whole line and assign it to a single string variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `Print #1, x, y`, the values of `x` and `y` will be written to a single line in the text file separated by a `TAB` character.  Doing two separate `Print` statements will write each variable to a new line.  As stated in the comments Line Input will read a whole line into a single string.  This is why your final example works as each `Line Input` gets a new line to read.  If you want it all on one line then write it out with `Print #1, x, y` and then read it with something like:

```
Dim s as String
Dim values() as string
Line Input #1, s
values = Split(s, vbTab)
x = values(0)
y = values(1)
```

For this sort of thing you might be better looking at `Write` and `Input` which cater better for multiple variables on a line.  Sample taken from link below

```
Dim MyString, MyNumber 
Open "TESTFILE" For Input As #1    ' Open file for input. 
Do While Not EOF(1)    ' Loop until end of file. 
    Input #1, MyString, MyNumber    ' Read data into two variables. 
    Debug.Print MyString, MyNumber    ' Print data to the Immediate window. 
Loop 
Close #1    ' Close file.
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264519.aspx

Sorry I don't have access to a VB6 environment at the moment to give fuller examples.

Comment: Finally, thank you! I had been having so much trouble with trying to use print and input together but the moment I switched to write and input everything started working as intended. Once again thank you and I hope you have a great day!